# How to read the Excel (xlsx) Header column Data Type using apache POI 4.X

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have been struggling to find out the way to read the data type for each of the header columns.
I am using Apache POI 4.1.2 to read the XLSX file format using
XSSFWorkbook Implementation.

Business use case: I have an excel with 22 cells( includes string, Numeric, date field)
if user tries to modify the date field to String or Numeric to String or vice versa. I need to throw the errow without even reading the data rows. Thoug
h I am able to handle the data rows in case user modifies the type ( date value to varchar, Numeric to String)

Sudo code snippet:

```
XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.getRow(rownum:0);
for(int cellNum=0; cellNum<22;cellNum++){
  Cell cell = headerRow.getCell(cellNum);
  System.out.println(cell.getCellType()); 
// This always returns the string even though the header row has date and numeric fields)
}
```

None of the search or recommendation helped me with any leads or solution so looking for a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can identify column types based on headers. Headers are typically text (string) that we enter in the first row of the file. They do not hold any specific data type.

On the other hand if you have to understand column types then you have to read from 2nd row of the file (leaving the headers).

Here is some implementation which does pretty good job at analyzing column types. You can mention how many rows to consider for analysis and which sheet to analyze

**Code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String excelFileName = "C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\test.xlsx";
        int sheet_num = 0;
        int maxRows_ToAnalyze = 5;
        
        Map<Integer, String> result = analyzeColumnTypes(excelFileName, sheet_num, maxRows_ToAnalyze);
        
        for(int i : result.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Column "+i+" is of type ==> "+result.get(i));
        }
        
    }
    
    static String NUMERIC = "NUMERIC";
    static String DATE = "DATE";
    static String STRING = "STRING";
    static String FORMULA = "FORMULA";
    static String BLANK = "BLANK";
    static String BOOLEAN = "BOOLEAN";
    static String ERROR = "ERROR";
    static String NOT_CONSISTENT = "NOT_CONSISTENT";

    public static Map<Integer, String> analyzeColumnTypes(String excelFileName, int sheet_num, int maxRows_ToAnalyze){
        
        Workbook workbook = null;
        Map<Integer, String> columnTypeMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        Map<Integer, Set<String>> tempMap = new HashMap<>();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^0-9\\.]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        try {
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFileName));
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheet_num);
            int rows_in_sheet = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            
            //if sheet rows are less than number of rows to analyze then analyze all the rows
            if(rows_in_sheet<maxRows_ToAnalyze) {
                maxRows_ToAnalyze = rows_in_sheet;
            }
            
            //i=1 because we dont want to read header rows
            //header rows are typically strings
            for(int i=1; i<=maxRows_ToAnalyze; i++) {
                
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                int column_count = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

                for(int j=0; j<column_count; j++) {
                    
                    tempMap.putIfAbsent(j, new HashSet<>());

                    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    
                    if(cell.getCellType().equals(CellType.NUMERIC)) {

                        Matcher m = p.matcher(cell.toString());
                        boolean match = m.find();
                        
                        if(match) {
                            tempMap.get(j).add(DATE);
                        } else {
                            tempMap.get(j).add(NUMERIC);
                        }
                        
                    } else if(cell.getCellType().equals(CellType.STRING)) {
                        tempMap.get(j).add(STRING);
                    } else if(cell.getCellType().equals(CellType.FORMULA)) {
                        tempMap.get(j).add(FORMULA);
                    } else if(cell.getCellType().equals(CellType.BLANK)) {
                        tempMap.get(j).add(BLANK);
                    } else if(cell.getCellType().equals(CellType.BOOLEAN)) {
                        tempMap.get(j).add(BOOLEAN);
                    } else if(cell.getCellType().equals(CellType.ERROR)) {
                        tempMap.get(j).add(ERROR);
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        for(int colnum: tempMap.keySet()) {
            if(tempMap.get(colnum).size()>1) {
                columnTypeMap.put(colnum, NOT_CONSISTENT);
            } else {
                for(String coltype: tempMap.get(colnum)) {
                    columnTypeMap.put(colnum, coltype);
                }
            }
        }

        return columnTypeMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you have to check first if cell is not null:    if (cell == null) {
tempMap.get(j).add(BLANK);
                    } //or ERROR